# insert data into other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below query which gives 10 records at a time and I want to save the data into another table, how to do that?

```
DELETE FROM TestQueue WITH (READPAST) OUTPUT DELETED.*
WHERE TestQueue.Id IN
(
 SELECT TOP(10) Id -- maximum batch size
 FROM TestQueue
 WHERE Data >= 0 AND Data <= 1000 -- selection criteria
 ORDER BY Id ASC
)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: The query is for deleting the entry, not for to selecting entry and saving it in another table.

Comment: it's gave result set as well and I want to store it in different table

Comment: you can try trigger after delete..using the trigger you can save it another table..

Comment: INSERT INTO dbo.tmpAlarmListDetailed_COPY (ALRM_DETECTION_UTC_DATE, SITE_ORIGINATOR_ID, DEVICE_NAME, ALRM_DETECTION_USER_DATE)

 SELECT ALRM_DETECTION_UTC_DATE, SITE_ORIGINATOR_ID, DEVICE_NAME, ALRM_DETECTION_USER_DATE FROM 
 (
 
  DELETE FROM dbo.tmpAlarmListDetailed WITH (READPAST) OUTPUT DELETED.*
  WHERE tmpAlarmListDetailed.U_ID IN
  (SELECT TOP(10) tmpAlarmListDetailed.U_ID
    FROM dbo.tmpAlarmListDetailed
    ORDER BY tmpAlarmListDetailed.U_ID ASC)

 ) X

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @piyushj: the `DELETE` statement has an **`OUTPUT`** clause which returns the data being deleted *as a result set* which can then be inserted into another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps.

1. create a output table with required columns

   ```
    CREATE TABLE  dbo.t_audit (Id int not null);
   ```
2. Using the OUTPUT clause ,select the required values that you wanted to keep.

   ```
    DELETE FROM TestQueue WITH (READPAST) 
    OUTPUT DELETED.ID INTO t_audit 
    WHERE TestQueue.Id IN (SELECT TOP(10) Id -- maximum batch size
                           FROM TestQueue
                           WHERE Data >= 0 AND Data <= 1000 -- selection criteria
                           ORDER BY Id ASC)
   ```

Comment: Thanks marc.. i was not able to format the script from my system.